# Silverlight progress bar tri color

Tags: silverlight

Is it possible to make the progress bar in silverlight tri color? i.e red for % error green for % Success/Completed and grey for remaining.

Many thanks,
Jane

Comment: http://blogs.silverlight.net/blogs/msnow/archive/2008/09/29/silverlight-tip-of-the-day-49-how-to-implement-a-progress-bar.aspx

Answer (score 0):

not possible with a progress bar, try creating your own control.

Answer (score 0):

The link below is another example of changing the color of a ProgressBar element. Note though that this is the ProgressBar, not the BusyIndicator which does not allow color change (in case that's what you were using). They are otherwise virtually interchangeable.

http://www.silverlightshow.net/items/The-ProgressBar-control-in-Silverlight-2.aspx

To do tri-color you just need to change the foreground color on the fly as your criteria changes.